# Minecraft java ca-certs and fedora 28

Tags: ssl, certificate, fedora, minecraft

I've come to ask about a problem that has been effecting a few linux distors recently. Mainly Linux Mint and Fedora. I play minecraft on occasion and make plugins and such. So whenever I try to join a server it fails and says (authentication servers are down) when they obviously are not.

Further research on the topic showed that if you update-ca-certs on mint it fixes it. Though there isn't that command on fedora and update-ca-trust doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Hey! I don't believe this question is suited for StackOverflow. We usually answer questions regarding Programming, and unless I understood it wrong, yours isn't about programming.

Comment: I believe you'd be better answered in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: If your question is indeed about programming, please edit it to include what piece of code is causing you troubles, or what you're trying to accomplish via code, ok?

Comment: ye. my bad mate.